# How can I connect an IBOutlet from my code to two different objects in interface builder

Tags: iphone, iboutlet

I'm using the iPhone SDK 4.0 and I want to connect `IBOutlet UIImageView *block;` to more than one image on the view in interface builder. However, whenever I try and link the second image, the first image becomes disconnected.
How can I connect two images to the same IBOutlet code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IBOutlet variables have a *one-to-one* relationship with objects in interface builder.  Therefore you will have to have another variable.

Comment: Just what @Jesse said, ... IBOutlets are unlike IBActions which can have a many connections.  While a Button can cause many actions to occur, the UIImageView can only display a single image at a time.

Comment: I'm not trying to display two images in the same imageview, i'm trying to display two imageview in the same view.
I guess that means I need to write another IBOutlet for a *block2 and rewrite all the code judging by what's been said

Answer (score 1):

put them in two different xib file then can access them using a single iboutlet using the code [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tests" owner:self options:nil];